# JSF2 Session issue

Tags: java, facebook, spring, jsf

Here i am checking In a LoginBean.java a Sessionscoped bean I have this code

Call from `MyPage.xhtml`

```
public String Method1(){
    HttpSession  secondSession =  (HttpSession) FacesContext.
                     getCurrentInstance().
                     getExternalContext().
                     getSession(false);
                    System.out.println(secondSession.getId());
}
```

result coming 9B4CB2748A440FEF1B2B4A7AEF401BFF

In same bean i have another method which is called from another JSF page 
call from `MyAnotherPage.xhtml`

```
 public String Method2(){
    HttpSession  secondSession =  (HttpSession) FacesContext.
                     getCurrentInstance().
                     getExternalContext().
                     getSession(false);
                    System.out.println(secondSession.getId());
}
```

result coming 3F9F2F1CF9C9A0A56B44AB5DB04ABF12

Look it created two different session id it mean two different session .Now issue is that if in first method i am adding any attribute in session i am not able to get that attribute in second method .What is going wrong Why different session for different request ?

**Note:-** Second method call after user successfully login from Facebook so it is CallbackOurl which add **Twitter** APPS.

```
http://127.0.0.1:8080/mywebapp/login/MyAnotherPage.xhtml
```

and i am calling method like this from this xhtml page

```
<f:event listener="#{TwitterManagedBean.redirectTwitterLogin2}" type="preRenderView" />
```

How i set the attribute

```
HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) FacesContext
                .getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequest();
        HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) FacesContext
                .getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getResponse();
        try {
            Twitter twitter = new TwitterFactory().getInstance();
            RequestToken requestToken;
            request.getSession().setAttribute("twitter", twitter);
            twitter.setOAuthConsumer("***********","***************"
                    );
            requestToken = twitter
                    .getOAuthRequestToken("http://127.0.0.1:8080/3c/login/TwitterLogin.xhtml");
            String authURL = requestToken.getAuthenticationURL();
            request.getSession().setAttribute("requestToken", requestToken);
            response.sendRedirect(authURL);
        } catch (TwitterException twitterException) {
            twitterException.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Return Back Like this

```
 public void fetchUserInfo( )
                throws TwitterException {
            HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) FacesContext
                    .getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequest();
            Map<String, Object> requestMap = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequestMap();
            Twitter value = (Twitter) requestMap.get("twitter");
            Twitter twitter = (Twitter) request.getSession()
                    .getAttribute("twitter");//Here Null
            RequestToken requestToken = (RequestToken) request.getSession()
                    .getAttribute("requestToken");//Here Null

            accessToken = twitter.getOAuthAccessToken(requestToken, verifier);
            request.getSession().removeAttribute("requestToken");
            userId = accessToken.getUserId();
            User user = twitter.showUser(userId);
            avatarUrl = user.getProfileImageURL().toString();
            screenName = user.getScreenName();
        }
```

Comment: Maybe you should pass true value to getSession() method

Comment: Brother If the create parameter is true, create (if necessary) and return a session instance associated with the current request And here issue is that if i am setting any attribute in session i am not able to get back,Always coming null

Comment: Can you provide the setAttribute code and the xhtml page?

Comment: @ForguesR  Added Java Method

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this, may be this will solve your issue. This works for me.

```
FacesContext facesContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
HttpSession httpSession = (HttpSession) facesContext.getExternalContext().getSession(true);
```

Comment: Sorry @Aashi its giving same null.If method call from same JSF page then it giving same session id if coming from another page sessioid changed